# How to delete the predefined mDNS rule in ufw with Ansible?

Tags: centos, ansible, ufw

I'm setting up a centOS 7 server with Ansible 2.6 and ufw as my firewall. Ufw comes with two predefined rules: SSH and mDNS.

While I can easily delete the SSH rule with my playbook:

```
- name: delete SSH rule by name
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    name: SSH
    delete: yes
```

For the mDNS rule my script doesn't work:

> predefined ufw rule:
>
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 5353/udp (mDNS) ALLOW IN    Anywhere
>
> xyz::xyz 5353/udp (mDNS)   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

My attempts in the playbook:

```
- name: delete mDNS rule by name
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    name: mDNS
    delete: yes
```

or

```
- name: delete mDNS rule 
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    to_ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    to_port: 5353
    proto: udp
    delete: yes
```

In both cases, Ansible reports an "ok" statment but the mDNS rule is still present.

> TASK [delete mDNS rule by name] ************
>
> ok: [host ip]
>
> TASK [delete mDNS rule]  ************
>
> ok: [host ip]

Is there a way with ansible? I want to automate my project as much as possible.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions related to software development. You should probably ask this over on https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Now I'm confused. My question is how to develop an ansible playbook that can delete the mDNS rule. I can delete the rule manually by number, but how can i write a task in ansible?
@larsks you still recommend to move it over?

Comment: I guess one could argue either way. Feel free to leave it here a bit and see what happens.  I don't know the answer myself.

Comment: @larsks thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```yaml
- name: Delete UFW default IPv6 mDNS rule
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    direction: in
    dest: xxxx::xx
    name: mDNS
    delete: yes

- name: Delete UFW default IPv4 mDNS rule
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    direction: in
    dest: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    name: mDNS
    delete: yes
```

I know it's a bit late for a response, but I just finally worked it out myself.